# Asymptote code for point, segment, and some 3D prisms (Overleaf), project due this evening!

Tags: 3d, asymptote, polygon

I’m very bad at `Asymptote` and I need to create a version of the following diagram (if this doesn’t work, see screenshot, except without that grey dot which somehow got in my screenshot)[image]:

```
\begin{asymptote}
unitsize(0.5cm);

for (int n = 1; n <= 6; ++n) {
picture p;
for (int i =0; i <= 6; ++i) {
draw(p, expi(-pi/2+(2i-1)*pi/n)--expi(-pi/2+(2i+1)*pi/n));
dot(p, expi(-pi/2+(2i-1)*pi/n));
}
add(shift((3*n, cos(pi/n)))*p);
}
\end{asymptote}
```

except with those polygons being in 3D. I am trying to learn `Asymptote`, but right now I’m too busy editing my project (due tonight), so it would be great if someone could create the `asymptote` diagram for this. I hope this isn’t too challenging to make, I will be very grateful if someone creates the diagram :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how about with tikz-euclide

Comment: @jsbibra I don’t know how to use that, sorry. Thanks for recommending it though.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "except with those polygons being in 3D" -- are you trying to draw polyhedrons?

Comment: Aah, the familiar "project [is] due this evening!" plea for help. Here's another familiar saying: "Lack of planning on your part does not constitute an emergency on my part."

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX.SX!  You might care to read the [TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436), which explains that this is not really supposed to be a "please do this for me" site.  You will get better answers to specific questions, rather than appeals for help with assignments.

There are some [good tutorials](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/doc/Tutorial.html) available for Asymptote, and if you really want 3D it is probably the best tool for that. But if you want the 2D polygons you show, then you could also consider TikZ as recommended in the comments or (my preference) [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).

Here is a version of your diagram in MP. This is wrapped up in `luamplib` so you will need to compile it with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    numeric r; r = 21;
    path C, c; c = fullcircle scaled 2r rotated 90;
    for n=1 upto 6:
        C := c if not odd n: rotated (180/n) fi 
               shifted ((2.8n, sind(90-180/n)) * r);
        draw point 0 of C for i=1 upto n: -- point 8i / n of C endfor;
        for i=1 upto n: 
            drawdot point 8i / n of C withpen pencircle scaled 4; 
        endfor
    endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

The only tricky bit here is adjusting each of the circle paths so that
the polygons drawn round them sit on the baseline.  This is done by rotating the even numbered ones, and shifting them vertically by `sind(90-180/n)` times the radius.

Notice also that MP's `for` loop can be used "inline" when required.

Answer (score 0):

First, using TikZ (this is simplest one I think):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,nodes={circle,draw,fill=red},inner sep=1.5pt]
\def\a{1} % length of an edge
\path (0,0) node{}; 

\draw[shift={(0:1)}] (0,0) node{}--(0:\a) node{}; 

\draw[shift={(0:3)}] (0,0) node{}--(0:\a) node{}--
([turn]120:\a) node{}--cycle; 

\draw[shift={(0:5)}] (0,0) node{}--(0:\a) node{}--
([turn]90:\a) node{}--
([turn]90:\a) node{}--cycle; 

\draw[shift={(0:7)}] (0,0) node{}--(0:\a) node{}--
([turn]72:\a) node{}--
([turn]72:\a) node{}--
([turn]72:\a) node{}--cycle; 

\draw[shift={(0:9.5)}] (0,0) node{}--(0:\a) node{}--
([turn]60:\a) node{}--
([turn]60:\a) node{}--
([turn]60:\a) node{}--
([turn]60:\a) node{}--cycle; 

\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{center}
\lipsum[10] 
\end{document}
```

`Asymptote` code will be given later!